# GNU MPFR give me exact same results on precision higher than 64

Tags: c++, mpfr

I'm trying to make some research on IIR precision, so I write a simple IIR using GNU MPFR:

```
#include <mpfr.h>

class DirectFormIIR
{
public:
    DirectFormIIR( int precision );
    ~DirectFormIIR();

    void setParams( double b0, double b1, double b2, double a1, double a2 );
    void resetState();

    double process( double x0 );
    void process( mpfr_t output, mpfr_t input );

private:
    void _process();
    mpfr_t x0;
    mpfr_t x1;
    mpfr_t x2;
    mpfr_t y0;
    mpfr_t y1;
    mpfr_t y2;
    mpfr_t b0;
    mpfr_t b1;
    mpfr_t b2;
    mpfr_t a1;
    mpfr_t a2;
    mpfr_t tmp;

};

DirectFormIIR::DirectFormIIR( int precision )
{
    mpfr_inits2( precision, x0, x1, x2, y0, y1, y2, b0, b1, b2, a1, a2, tmp, NULL );
}

DirectFormIIR::~DirectFormIIR()
{
    mpfr_clears( x0, x1, x2, y0, y1, y2, b0, b1, b2, a1, a2, tmp, NULL );
}

void DirectFormIIR::setParams( double b0, double b1, double b2, double a1, double a2 )
{
    mpfr_set_d( this->b0, b0, MPFR_RNDN );
    mpfr_set_d( this->b1, b1, MPFR_RNDN );
    mpfr_set_d( this->b2, b2, MPFR_RNDN );
    mpfr_set_d( this->a1, a1, MPFR_RNDN );
    mpfr_set_d( this->a2, a2, MPFR_RNDN );
}

void DirectFormIIR::resetState()
{
    mpfr_set_zero( this->x0, 0 );
    mpfr_set_zero( this->x1, 0 );
    mpfr_set_zero( this->x2, 0 );
    mpfr_set_zero( this->y0, 0 );
    mpfr_set_zero( this->y1, 0 );
    mpfr_set_zero( this->y2, 0 );
}

void DirectFormIIR::process( mpfr_t output, mpfr_t input )
{
    mpfr_set( x0, input, MPFR_RNDN );
    _process();
    mpfr_set( output, y0, MPFR_RNDN );
}

void DirectFormIIR::_process()
{
    // calculate current Y
    mpfr_mul( tmp, b0, x0, MPFR_RNDN );
    mpfr_set( y0, tmp, MPFR_RNDN );
    mpfr_mul( tmp, b1, x1, MPFR_RNDN );
    mpfr_add( y0, y0, tmp, MPFR_RNDN );
    mpfr_mul( tmp, b2, x2, MPFR_RNDN );
    mpfr_add( y0, y0, tmp, MPFR_RNDN );

    mpfr_mul( tmp, a1, y1, MPFR_RNDN );
    mpfr_sub( y0, y0, tmp, MPFR_RNDN );
    mpfr_mul( tmp, a2, y2, MPFR_RNDN );
    mpfr_sub( y0, y0, tmp, MPFR_RNDN );

    // update history
    mpfr_set( y2, y1, MPFR_RNDN );
    mpfr_set( y1, y0, MPFR_RNDN );
    mpfr_set( x2, x1, MPFR_RNDN );
    mpfr_set( x1, x0, MPFR_RNDN );
}
```

However, calculating results exceeding 64-bit precision always give me exact same result. I'm pretty sure my parameters are working properly, as it generates correct equalizer effect, and there are differences on 32-bit and higher outputs.

The code below is where IIR is run, note that differences of two IIR is amplified 100000 times to avoid being vanished:

```
    int prec_high = std::max( prec1, prec2 );
    mpfr_t x, yprec1, yprec2, ydiff;
    mpfr_inits2( prec_high, x, yprec1, yprec2, ydiff, nullptr );
    DirectFormIIR iir1( prec1 );
    DirectFormIIR iir2( prec2 );
    iir1.setParams( b0, b1, b2, a1, a2 );
    iir2.setParams( b0, b1, b2, a1, a2 );
    for ( int ch = 0; ch < reader->numChannels; ch++ )
    {
        iir1.resetState();
        iir2.resetState();
        for ( int i = 0; i < audio_data.getNumSamples(); i++ )
        {
            mpfr_set_flt( x, audio_data.getSample( ch, i ), MPFR_RNDN );
            iir1.process( yprec1, x );
            iir2.process( yprec2, x );
            mpfr_sub( ydiff, yprec1, yprec2, MPFR_RNDN );
            mpfr_set_d( x, 100000.0, MPFR_RNDN );
            mpfr_mul( ydiff, ydiff, x, MPFR_RNDN );
            audio_data.setSample( ch, i, mpfr_get_flt( ydiff, MPFR_RNDN ) );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The effect you obtain is typically due to the fact that `double` is used somewhere in the program while it should not be.

In your case, your inputs are numbers of type `double`, i.e. with a fixed 53-bit precision. So, the accuracy of the computed result will be limited because of that. Increasing the precision of the computations would help only if significant additional errors are introduced in these computations, but this does not seem to be the case here.

So, if you want more accurate results, you need to increase the accuracy of the inputs (both by choosing a type allowing a larger precision than 53 bits and by making sure that they really are more accurate).

Answer (score 0):

I did not set enough scaling to the difference value. After I increased it from 100000 to 1e15, the difference became visible.